# PHP Curl get information from a Website which loaded with JavaScript

Tags: php, web, curl

I have a big problem and I could not find any help in other Forums.

My problem:
I make a **Android App** for a swimming club.
One function of the App is to manage the swimmer.
So i like to find automatically they best swimming time with only their names.

> There is a website with this function :
>   http://www.dsv.de/schwimmen/wettkampf-national/schwimmerabfrage/

There I must insert a first name(Vorname) and a surname (Nachname) and confirm this with a button. For example: Paul Biedermann.

Then I must click on best times (Bestzeiten) on the right and then i see a table with all the information.
And i like to find the information with **PHP** and safe it to my Databank.

This was my try:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://dsvdaten.dsv.de/Modules/Results/Individual.aspx?Lang=de-DE';
$data = array('_firstnameTextBox' => 'vorname', '_lastnameTextBox' => 'nachname');
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }
var_dump($result);
?>
```

But I do not figure out how I get the table of this site.

Comment: a HTTP request to the page only returns the HTML as it exists when the server first creates it. No JavaScript can be executed because there's no browser involved - cURL has replaced it as the client. So anything generated by JavaScript is out of reach. If the content you want is actually fetched by an AJAX call within this page, then load this page in your browser and use your browser's developer tools to see what request the page makes to its server. Then you can write a separate cURL request to emulate that and fetch the relevant data, if the server allows it.

Comment: So, are you running PHP inside of the AndroidApp? and there's no cURL in your question.

Comment: Don't think you can do it, since they have Form Validation enabled. Which means the validation code is changed for each response/session. So if you fetch/get the page, and then post to it, with the validation code, it's already been changed, since it's counts as a new session.

Comment: @Anuga it _is_ possible to get round that if it's a CSRF protection by parsing the token from the page and then sending it in the POST, and employing session cookies as well. But it's a fair bit of work.

Comment: nah, they have private cache on the page, so it would change between the parsing of the page and posting to the page. PHP doesn't keep the session open on the page in between.